# Bash script calling mysql after ssh returns access denied

Tags: linux, bash, stdin, heredoc

I am having a little trouble with a bash script im writing, i can run the individual commands in terminal and it works just fine, but running from a bash script is returning the error;

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The bash script is as follows;

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@myhost.com << EOF
    /usr/bin/mysql -h localhost -u root -p_kHaTX(!G_$=Y5Xa
    show databases;
EOF
```

I have tried to also wrap the password in '' like so

```
/usr/bin/mysql -h localhost -u root -p'_kHaTX(!G_$=Y5Xa'
```

and still nothing

But if I run the commands myself through the terminal, it all works just fine

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This might help: [Is it possible to use multiple here-docs in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148132/74329)

Comment: This might help, too: `echo 'show databases;' | /usr/bin/mysql -h localhost -u root '-p_kHaTX(!G_$=Y5Xa'`

Comment: @Cyrus ... Still the same errors being returned

Comment: test with this command : mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 --password=YOUR_PASS

Comment: @JJJ if i run that in the terminal i get -bash: !: event not found and if i run it from my script, i get -bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: try with password between "" like this: mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 --password="YOUR_PASS"

Comment: @JJJ Doing that i get the same error im seeing at the top in my question

Comment: Use a password without `!` and `$` to limit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error, and for security purposes also, store the password in a separate file, let's say:

```
echo '_kHaTX(!G_$=Y5Xa' > /root/mysql_pwd
```

Then pass the password as variable:

```
MYSQL_PWD=`cat /root/mysql_pwd` /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p -e "show databases"
```